# I can't connect grafana with mysql database running in the same ubuntu server VM

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vmware, grafana

I'm trying to connect a mysql database as grafana data source but I get:
`connect: connection refused`.
Grafana and mysql server both are running over Ubuntu server VM (vmware) and I can access to Grafana (which is installed as docker) using my VM IP address `192.168.1.130:3000`. Database is running in the virtual machine localhost because I insert into it datas.

I've tryed with `localhost:3306` and with `192.168.1.130:3306`, I've created a user for grafana with the privileges and flush it.

I have the port 3306 open in my NAT router for `localhost` and `192.168.1.130` but no works.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Did configure or disbaled your firewall ?

Comment: Yes, I have the ubuntu ufw innactive, in my router "Security -> IP filtering -> Incoming" and the windows firewall disable

Comment: Maybe your MySQL database is only bound to localhost and not on all interfaces? How did you connect to your database for creating the user? From inside the vm or from your host? Can you access the database using some admin tool (MySQL workbench, datagrip, heidisql) on the host system?

Answer (score 0):

It's a docker problem, I've read about the same problem and it's something about docker ports...so I've installed Grafana by the linux way and it work right now.

Fix docker ports seems hard and I dont understand...if someone can fix it tell me just to know and learn.

Thanks